# how to get a alert message each time i refresh the browser in flex

Tags: java, actionscript-3, tomcat, flex4, blazeds

i have a login system done in flex.once the user logs in and if he refreshes the page it will take you back to the login page.how can i make the logged in user stay in the same page using flex and java only?and also if once user is logged in and another loggs in with the same user name and passwrod how can i handle dat using flex and java? please help me
thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to look into [deep linking](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7cb6.html). It allows you to bring the user to a specific state in the application by passing in values after the the pound sign in a URL.

For example, http://example.com/app.html#post=1 could navigate the application and show the user the state of the application as if the user had navigated to the first post themselves.

This approach takes advantage of the fact that web browsers do not reload the page/app for URLs that are subsequently requested again with the pound sign in them. So, with Flash, the application wont be reloaded.

Comment: Using deep linking to keep the user on the same page is a good idea.  However, you shouldn't use it just to bypass a login screen.

Comment: I purposefully avoided mentioning how to keep a user logged in after the application was refreshed because I don't have a solution for that off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your Flex application sends requests to your Java back end, including login requests.

The easier approach would be to implement your login page as JSP or some other Java technology.  The site could be configured such that accessing the page hosting the Flex application requires that the user is logged in.

If you want to do the login through Flex, you could set an auth token cookie once the user has logged in, and then check to see if the cookie has already been set.  You'd also have to make sure your client handles the case where the authorization may have expired and show the login screen again.